# Adding user password to an AD with PHP

Tags: php, ldap

My API (wrote in PHP) needs to register a new user in an AD. It's like the `userPassword` attribute does not set the password of the user (so he cannot log in).

Things I've tried :

- Send the password in plain text : nOK
- Send the password with Base64 encoding : nOK

I've read an article ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2)) about `unicodePwd` and the use of LDAPS, but I'm not really sure how to implement this.

I'm actually working with a non-TLS LDAP connection (it's on a local network so I don't need it) on Win2k16 (latest version).

Domain is **secureconnect.online** (in my code it's **.local** but don't mind about it).

Here's my code :

```
public function addUser()
{
// LDAP variables
$ldap_username = $this->ldap_creds['username'];
$ldap_password = $this->ldap_creds['password'];
$ldapuri = $this->ldap_creds['uri'];

// LDAP connection
$link_id = ldap_connect($ldapuri);
if ($link_id) {

    ldap_set_option($link_id, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    ldap_bind($link_id, $ldap_username, $ldap_password);

    $lastname = strtolower($this->validFormData[0]);
    $firstname = strtolower($this->validFormData[1]);

    $username = $firstname . $lastname;
    $display_name = ucwords($firstname) . " " . ucwords($lastname);

    $unhashed_pass = $this->validFormData[8];
    $encoded_newPassword = "{SHA}" . base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1($unhashed_pass)));

    $adduserAD["cn"] = $username;
    $adduserAD["givenname"] = ucwords($firstname);
    $adduserAD["sn"] = ucwords($lastname);
    $adduserAD["sAMAccountName"] = $username;
    $adduserAD['userPrincipalName'] = $this->validFormData[2];
    $adduserAD["objectClass"] = "user";
    $adduserAD["displayname"] = $display_name;
    $adduserAD["userPassword"] = $encoded_newPassword;
    $adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = "544";
    $adduserAD['postalCode'] = $this->validFormData[5];
    // Add city
    $adduserAD['l'] = $this->validFormData[6];
    // Add street address
    $adduserAD['streetAddress'] = $this->validFormData[4];

    $dn = 'OU=Users-VPN,DC=secureconnect,DC=local';
    $base_dn = 'cn=' . $adduserAD['cn'] . ',' . $dn;

    $req = ldap_add($link_id, $base_dn, $adduserAD);
    if ($req) {
        $this->result = $username;
        ldap_close($link_id);
    } else {
        $this->result = '{"error":"Contact Administrator"}';
    }
} else {
    $this->result = '{"error":"Cannot Connect To Ldap Server"}';
}
return $this->result;
}
```

Thank's in advance !

**EDIT :**
So, I've installed an AD LDS with a trusted root certificate. Now when I'm trying to connect with TLS to the server through my API, I'm stuck at this error :

```
Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Here's the code :

```
/**
 * Method used to add and user to an LDAP annuary.
 * @return bool|string
 */
public function addUser()
{
    // LDAP variables
    $ldap_username = $this->ldap_creds['username'];
    $ldap_password = $this->ldap_creds['password'];
    $ldapuri = $this->ldap_creds['uri'];

    // Connexion LDAP
    $link_id = ldap_connect($ldapuri);
    if ($link_id) {

        ldap_set_option($link_id, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        ldap_start_tls($link_id);
        echo "yeet";

        ldap_bind($link_id, $ldap_username, $ldap_password);
```

Everything beyond this snippet is the same as above.

What should I do ? Do I need to import the certificate to the Web server ?

Comment: according to Microsoft docs referenced Server2008 ( & presumably above ) can have password modified if `fAllowPasswordOperationsOverNonSecureConnection` has been set AND that `Active Directory is operating as AD LDS`. Is that the case?

Comment: I'm actually resinstalling my server to correspond to the doc.
But what about LDAPS ? Do I need it ?

Comment: To implement `ADLDS` the DC should not host `domain naming context` - the decisions involved in the design of your active directory are beyond me. Why not use TLS encryption?

Comment: Well it's just a standard AD, with an OU containing one other and finished...
I'm now reinstalling and I'll set the TLS encryption.
But I need to use the unicodePwd in my API, right ?

Comment: Yes I believe so. It's a long time since I programmed for AD but never had particular worries about passwords so should be ok

Comment: Don't worry, I'm still studying and I'm not English so I'm sorry if what I write is'nt very clear ^^'
So yeah, I'll use the `unicodePwd` attribute as wrote in the MSDN over a TLS-LDAP connection. I'll come back if any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have some documentation that explains the process and requirements for using LDAP for [Setting and Changing Microsoft Active Directory Passwords](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Setting%20and%20Changing%20Microsoft%20Active%20Directory%20Passwords)

- Yes you need encrypted connection
- By Default you need to use
  UnicodePwd (unless you [Enable UserPassword in Microsoft Active
  Directory](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Enable%20UserPassword%20in%20Microsoft%20Active%20Directory))

And there is a sample in JAVA that shows how we have performed the operation. Usually it works out best to create the user and then set the UnicodePwd value. 
We are not real sure why this is the case but issues have been encountered when attempting to both in one operation.

Additionally, often depending on your Microsoft Active Directory settings users are created as disabled and may need to be enabled to be effective.